# Pass a variable in an error message in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to pass a variable to a url in an error message. How can I implement this?

In views.py

```
        error_messages = {
        'inactivated': _('Please <a href="../send" click here to 
                          to receive an activation key.')
       }
```

I'd like to pass an email address to the send url when a user gets an inactivated error message and click the link.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

String formatting should work

```
foo = 'fooo'
bar = 'baar'
'%s %s' % (foo, bar)
>> 'fooo baar'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the variable as an URL:

In views.py

`context_data = {'retry_url': reverse(viewname="send_activation_email", args=(), kwargs={})}

return render(
    request, template_name="template.html", context=context_data)`

In template.html:

`<p><a href="{{ retry_url }}">click here</a> to receive an activation key.</p>`

Comment: That sounds right, but if I pass the url as part of a form error message, forms. ValidationError(invalid_messages['inactivated'], 
                                            code='inactivated'). Thanks.

Comment: Try this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html